# How to open the upper left context menu via keystroke (for PuTTY on Windows)

Tags: windows, putty, keystrokes

Does anybody know a keystroke to open the upper left context menu in Windows operating systems? I'm referring to the one listling:

- Restore
- Move
- Size
- Minimize
- Maximize
- Close

In particular I want to restart individual 'inactive' putty sessions without using the mouse by any chance.

Comment: Similar problem using putty for an employer via citrix: mouse clicks don't reach the actual application, so I get a generic context menu rather than putty's menu. I can't find any way to access settings. Anyone know a trick?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to  set **System menu appears on ALT-Space** or **System menu appears on ALT alone** in PuTTY's Windows | Behaviour settings.

Comment: Blast. I'd *just* gotten there. :-)

Comment: That's what I looked for. Cheers!

Comment: This is the first program I've ever wanted to access this menu for and the shortcut was disabled by default... Why?... I was so confused that I was looking up how to do it in general because I thought I had the key combo wrong when it didn't work. Does alt+space do something special on a terminal too? I think it should be enabled by default.

Answer (score 7):

Just adding to the answer from [Mike Fitzpatrick](https://superuser.com/users/20444/mike-fitzpatrick)

In order for the changes to be effective, you need to:
Open the context menu (upper left) >  Click Change Settings... > Windows (Left Pane) > Behaviour 
Tick one of the items "System menu appears on.." 
 and click "Apply"